# Ambiguous RxJS Observable Behaviour for Mongo Cursor

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, database-cursor

I have been trying to write some code making a mongo cursor into an observable. I have found many solutions online but I've attempted to create mine from scratch to learn RxJS.

Would somebody please be able to explain why the following code gives the output below?

```
export function cursor$ <T> (cursor: Cursor<T>): Observable<T> {

    let counter = 1

    const d$ = (): Observable<T> => {
        counter++
        return from(cursor.hasNext())
            .pipe(
                tap(() => console.log(counter, 'before')),
                concatMap(x => x ? from( <Promise<T>>cursor.next() ) : empty()),
                tap(() => console.log(counter, 'between')),
                expand(() => d$()),
                tap(() => console.log(counter, 'after'))
            )
    }

    return d$()
}
```

Each item is logged in the subscribe and 'done' is printed on completion.

```
2 'before'
2 'between'
2 'after'
{ _id: 5bb5d47bbfa2d3ea077c37a6, name: 'Jeff' }
3 'before'
3 'between'
3 'after'
3 'after'
{ _id: 5bb5d483bfa2d3ea077c37a8, name: 'Jerald' }
5 'before'
5 'before'
5 'between'
5 'after'
5 'after'
{ _id: 5bb5d493bfa2d3ea077c37aa, name: 'Somebody' }
7 'between'
7 'after'
7 'after'
7 'after'
{ _id: 5bb5df8dbfa2d3ea077c39c8, name: 'Waddup' }
10 'before'
10 'before'
10 'before'
10 'before'
10 'before'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it!

The problem was that I was calling expand within `d$()` which itself was called multiple times.

Heres there working code with `tap()`s:

```
export function cursor$ <T> (cursor: Cursor<T>): Observable<T> {

    let counter = 0

    const next$ = () => from(cursor.hasNext())
        .pipe(
            tap(() => console.log(counter++, 'before')),
            concatMap(x => x ? from(<Promise<T>> cursor.next()) : empty()),
            tap(() => console.log(counter++, 'after')),
        )

    return next$().pipe(expand(() => next$()))
}
```

And the desired output:

```
0 'before'
1 'after'
{ _id: 5bb5d47bbfa2d3ea077c37a6, name: 'Jeff' }
2 'before'
3 'after'
{ _id: 5bb5d483bfa2d3ea077c37a8, name: 'Jerald' }
4 'before'
5 'after'
{ _id: 5bb5d493bfa2d3ea077c37aa, name: 'Somebody' }
6 'before'
7 'after'
{ _id: 5bb5df8dbfa2d3ea077c39c8, name: 'Waddup' }
8 'before'
done
```